# stop the text carret to move the viewport

Tags: html, css

my problem is that I can't stop the text carret to move my viewport. I guess it's easy to see the problem when you click on the grey field in my example and keep holding enter until the view moves. Even limiting the DIV height doesn't to anything. Any ideas?

```
<div id="one" contenteditable=true>clicker here and hold enter pressed</div>

#one {
    background:grey;
    max-height:100px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oxdGv

Answer (score -1):

You can't limit the height of the `contenteditable` content within the `div` per se- when you press enter, the standard behaviour of content 'spilling out' of the `div` happens, you can also see this if you simply add a lot of e.g. `text<br>` into it.

What you likely want to do is control the way the overflow on the `div` is handled, so if the content exceeds the available space, whether it is shown, hidden or scrolled. As such- to implement scrolling you can do:

```
#one {
    background:grey;
    max-height:100px;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

If you wish to actually limit the amount of lines avaiable, you'll need to resort to JS.